# NullPointerException converting String to Float

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

On Android I'm going from one screen to another.  On the first screen a number is written to a file (Say 500), then on the second screen it is read and assigned to a value of an Array.  I know this works fine because it will properly display this value from the Array while it is still a String.

The problem is I get a Nullpointerexception when I convert this value to a Float or an Int and try to use it in other places in the code.  Naturally when I have the phone plugged in during testing it's not reading the file from my phones internal memory, so that would cause such an exception.  However if the only thing I change is making the floats hard coded to a number instead of trying to convert a String, then it works just fine.

```
String[] customTest = new String[4];
```

This is the Array.  customTest[0] remaining as a String displays just fine.

```
float count = Float.parseFloat(customTest[1]);
```

When I do the above (Also tried Float.valueOf) then try and use the count variable:

```
if (timerStringFormat.equals(df.format(randNumber)) || timerStringFormat.equals(df.format(randNumber2)) || timerStringFormat.equals(df.format(randNumber3))) {
        bgGreen = false;
        count -= 1.66;
```

I get the nullpointerexception, which I assume means the value is somehow null.  Am I not converting it correctly?  Maybe because the String comes from an Array?  I've also tried assigning the customTest[1] to a temporary variable, then converting that temp variable to a float with no success.  I've also tried making sure the attempted Float conversions happen after the file is read and the value is assigned to the array.  Any help would be appreciated.

Below is how the file assigns the values to the Array as requested.

```
try {

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File myFile = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
       // myFile.createNewFile();
        File file = new File(myFile, "rlglc.txt");
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String data = "";
        int i = 0;
        while ((data = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                customTest[i] = data;
            i++;

        } 
        myReader.close();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I know it works properly, because if I set it to display the value of any element of the Array on the screen, it does so just fine.  Only when I try to change the value to an Int or Float does it mess up.

Comment: most probably you do not have any thing inside your customTest array so the value is null. how you put value inside your array? can you show how you assigned your array?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NullPointerException`, so first be sure that **`customTest[1]` should never be null.**  When you are putting 
**`float count = Float.parseFloat(customTest[1]);`**, first log the value of `customTest[1]`, as I think `customTest[1]` is null.

Edit:

```
float count = 0;
if(customTest[1]!=null){
    count  = Float.parseFloat(customTest[1]);
}
```